We are receiving numerous email alerts from AWS CloudWatch Alarms. Is there a way to manage these alerts in more structured manner?
In our current AWS CloudWatch setup, we receive numerous alerts every minute, many of which are often ignored. We are looking for a more structured and organized way to collect and manage these alerts. We are open to integrating AI solutions to help us better manage and respond to these alerts effectively.
I was trying to resolve it through any centralized way. But I have no idea how to improve what we have done.

Build better alerts, if nothing is wrong you should not receive alerts. And if something is wrong you should ideally not receive hundreds of them but at most a couple.
